# Can i put web directory and other folders in different directories in symfony

Tags: symfony, controller, src

I am setting web folder in root directory of server where as other symfony folders as(app,src,bin,vendor in other directory) in other directery as **Details**

I want this type of setting as I don't want to give  direct access to app,src and other folder of symfony. **So initially app.php will called, which will call other PHP resources belongs to Details directory.**

Here is sample folder structure I want as following;

---Root
           ----web
             --app.php 
             --assets 
       ----Details
             --app
             --bin
             --src
             --var 
             --vendor

Comment: is it related to  something public and private directory

Comment: Have you tried using a symlink inside web?

Comment: no,i dont have idea about it,can u provide me link

Comment: "ln -s \Details \web\details" should do the trick. Also be sure that Details has lecture permissions to be read.

Comment: You are probably making life more difficult than is has to be.  Most web servers let you define some sort of virtual host which points directly to the web directory.  None of the other files will be exposed.  The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html) cover in detail how to setup your Symfony app for various types of servers.  Best to follow them at least until you have a better understanding of web servers.

Comment: i have made it by just changing  autoload.php path in app.php